# Search scope is finding deleted items

Tags: 2010, search, scope

Using `SharePoint 2010` I created a custom `search` scope to search for items on a specific `list` and it has been working great, until I `deleted` a ton of items from the list. Now the search scope is still finding those items and turning them up in the results. If you click on the title, it is an error message.

Once an item is deleted, I do not want it to turn up in the search but I cannot figure out how to do this.

I tried adding the recycle bin URL to the scope in order to exclude it, but that didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running a full crawl again?

Also, you might want to check on your values for the ErrorDeleteCountAllowed and ErrorDeleteIntervalAllowed properties as they affect some policies. Use PowerShell to change them:

```
$SearchApplication = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication -Identity "Search Service Application"
$SearchApplication.SetProperty("ErrorDeleteCountAllowed", 1)
$SearchApplication.SetProperty("ErrorDeleteIntervalAllowed",0)
```

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh127009(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Unfortunately I dont have access to PowerShell, but I did try to reset my crawl by deleting and reentering the scope and the display page but that didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to let it go and take a look at it the next day and found that all of the deleted items were gone so it may have just been the cache...?